# Creating a custom ODBC driver

Tags: sql, database, sdk, odbc, odbc-bridge

At my current job, we're looking to implement our own odbc driver to allow many different applications to be able to connect to our own app as a datasource. Right now we are trying to weigh the options of developing our own driver to the implementation spec, which is massive, *or* using an SDK that allows for programmers to 'fill in' the data specific parts and allow higher levels of abstraction.

Has anyone else implemented a custom odbc driver? What pitfalls did you run into? What benefits did you see from doing it yourself? How many manhours would you approximate it took? Did you use an SDK, and if so, what benefits/downsides did you see from that approach?

Any comments and answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** We are trying to maintain portability with our code, which is written in C.

Comment: Can I ask -  Why have you elected to build a custom odbc driver, (15 year old technology) rather than an oleDb driver (10 year old technology) or a managed code ADO,Net data provider (8 year old and current)  ??

Comment: Our code is written in C and we want it to maintain portability.

Comment: Also, quite a few systems (MSQuery and Access come to mind) were really designed with ODBC in mind and work best with this.

Comment: I was just curious..., examining this issue, I would have included the potential market for the component in my decision factors...  Are the majority of your potential users using Access and.or MsQuery ?

Comment: Funny that now MS seems to be moving away from the "old" oledb to the "really old" odbc...

Comment: boomhauer is probably referencing Microsoft dropping the OLE DB provider after SQL Server 2010. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access.aspx

Comment: unixODBC and iODBC are ODBC driver managers not ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not, but I once interviewed at a company that had done exactly this.  They made
a 4GL/DBMS product called AMPS of the same sort of architecture as MUMPS - a hierarchical database with integrated 4GL (a whole genre of such systems came out during the 1970s).  They had quite a substantial legacy code base and customers wishing to connect to it using MS Access.

The lead developer who interviewed me shared some war stories about this.  Apparently it is exceedingly painful to do and shouldn't be taken lightly.  However, they did actually succeed in implemnenting it.

One alternative to doing this would be to provide a data mart/BI product (along the lines of SAP BW) that presents your application data in an external database and massages it into a more friendly format such as a star or snowflake schema.

This would suffer from not supporting real-time access, but might be considerably easier to implement (and more importantly maintain) than an ODBC driver.  If your real-time access requirements are reasonably predicitable and limited, you could possibly expose a web service API to support those.

Answer (score 30):

Another option: Instead of creating a ODBC driver, implement a back end that talks the wire protocol that another database (Postgresql or MySQL for instance) uses.

Your users can then download and use for instance the Postgresql ODBC driver.

Exactly what back-end database you choose to emulate should probably depend the most on how well the wire protocol format is documented.

Both [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) has decent documentation for their client-server protocols.

A simple Python 2.7 example of a server backend that understands parts of the Postgresql wire protocol is below. The example script creates a server that listens to port 9876. I can use the command `psql -h localhost -p 9876` to connect to the server. Any query executed will return a result set with columns abc and def and two rows, all values NULL.

Reading the Postgresql docs and using something like wireshark to inspect real protocol traffic would make it pretty simple to implement a Postgresql-compatible back end.

```
import SocketServer
import struct

def char_to_hex(char):
    retval = hex(ord(char))
    if len(retval) == 4:
        return retval[-2:]
    else:
        assert len(retval) == 3
        return "0" + retval[-1]

def str_to_hex(inputstr):
    return " ".join(char_to_hex(char) for char in inputstr)

class Handler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print "handle()"
        self.read_SSLRequest()
        self.send_to_socket("N")

        self.read_StartupMessage()
        self.send_AuthenticationClearText()
        self.read_PasswordMessage()
        self.send_AuthenticationOK()
        self.send_ReadyForQuery()
        self.read_Query()
        self.send_queryresult()

    def send_queryresult(self):
        fieldnames = ['abc', 'def']
        HEADERFORMAT = "!cih"
        fields = ''.join(self.fieldname_msg(name) for name in fieldnames)
        rdheader = struct.pack(HEADERFORMAT, 'T', struct.calcsize(HEADERFORMAT) - 1 + len(fields), len(fieldnames))
        self.send_to_socket(rdheader + fields)

        rows = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
        DRHEADER = "!cih"
        for row in rows:
            dr_data = struct.pack("!ii", -1, -1)
            dr_header = struct.pack(DRHEADER, 'D', struct.calcsize(DRHEADER) - 1 + len(dr_data), 2)
            self.send_to_socket(dr_header + dr_data)

        self.send_CommandComplete()
        self.send_ReadyForQuery()

    def send_CommandComplete(self):
        HFMT = "!ci"
        msg = "SELECT 2\x00"
        self.send_to_socket(struct.pack(HFMT, "C", struct.calcsize(HFMT) - 1 + len(msg)) + msg)

    def fieldname_msg(self, name):
        tableid = 0
        columnid = 0
        datatypeid = 23
        datatypesize = 4
        typemodifier = -1
        format_code = 0 # 0=text 1=binary
        return name + "\x00" + struct.pack("!ihihih", tableid, columnid, datatypeid, datatypesize, typemodifier, format_code)

    def read_socket(self):
        print "Trying recv..."
        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print "Received {} bytes: {}".format(len(data), repr(data))
        print "Hex: {}".format(str_to_hex(data))
        return data

    def send_to_socket(self, data):
        print "Sending {} bytes: {}".format(len(data), repr(data))
        print "Hex: {}".format(str_to_hex(data))
        return self.request.sendall(data)

    def read_Query(self):
        data = self.read_socket()
        msgident, msglen = struct.unpack("!ci", data[0:5])
        assert msgident == "Q"
        print data[5:]


    def send_ReadyForQuery(self):
        self.send_to_socket(struct.pack("!cic", 'Z', 5, 'I'))

    def read_PasswordMessage(self):
        data = self.read_socket()
        b, msglen = struct.unpack("!ci", data[0:5])
        assert b == "p"
        print "Password: {}".format(data[5:])


    def read_SSLRequest(self):
        data = self.read_socket()
        msglen, sslcode = struct.unpack("!ii", data)
        assert msglen == 8
        assert sslcode == 80877103

    def read_StartupMessage(self):
        data = self.read_socket()
        msglen, protoversion = struct.unpack("!ii", data[0:8])
        print "msglen: {}, protoversion: {}".format(msglen, protoversion)
        assert msglen == len(data)
        parameters_string = data[8:]
        print parameters_string.split('\x00')

    def send_AuthenticationOK(self):
        self.send_to_socket(struct.pack("!cii", 'R', 8, 0))

    def send_AuthenticationClearText(self):
        self.send_to_socket(struct.pack("!cii", 'R', 8, 3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer(("localhost", 9876), Handler)
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except:
        server.shutdown()
```

Example command line psql session:

```
[~]
$ psql -h localhost -p 9876
Password:
psql (9.1.6, server 0.0.0)
WARNING: psql version 9.1, server version 0.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

codeape=> Select;
 abc | def
-----+-----
     |
     |
(2 rows)

codeape=>
```

An ODBC driver that speaks the Postgresql protocol should work as well (but I have not tried it yet).

Comment: Currently trying to make it work with an ODBC driver and it looks promising. I just had to remove the SSLRequest part at the beginning and return results which correspond to what the ODBC driver is asking for, I can see all the requests coming by :)

Comment: Great answer! This is what the h2 database does: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver

Answer (score 11):

ODBC drivers are very complex - the decision to write one should not be taken lightly.  Reviewing existing open source drivers are a good approach for examples but most have shortcommings you may not want to emulate :)  APIs are the same regardless of OS platform.
FreeTDS for MSSQL/Sybase has one of the better open source ODBC Driver implementations I've seen.

If you control the application you can get away with implementing what may be just a very small subset of the spec in a reasonable amount of time. To use in a general purpose environment can require quite a bit more effort to get right.  Off the top of my head in addition to simply implementing dozens of wrapper calls you will also have to implement:

- Metadata access functions
- ODBC specific query syntax parsing
- SQLSTATE Error message mappings
- Multibyte/Character set marshalling
- ODBC version 2,3 support - error messages/function mappings
- Cursors
- DM configuration UI for managing the datasource

Comment: How about the MySQL ODBC driver, or the Postgresql ODBC driver? Does anyone have opinions on the code quality of these drivers?

Answer (score 4):

I have not implemented an ODBC driver, but just wanted to offer a suggestion that you can start with an open-source implementation and add your own customizations.  This may get you started a lot faster.

There are at least two options:

- [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) is licensed under LGPL, which means if you modify the code you have to make your modifications open-source.
- [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/) is licensed under either LGPL or New BSD, at your choice.  New BSD allows you to make modifications *without* make your modifications open-source.

However, it's not clear if these packages run on Windows, as opposed to running on UNIX/Linux with a client API consistent with standard ODBC.  You don't state which platform you're using, so I don't know if this is relevant to you.

Answer (score 3):

This post is now a bit old, but worth mentioning that if you need to have an ODBC driver, you can use an SDK like this: https://insightsoftware.com/drivers/simba-sdk/ It takes care of most of the points raised in the other answers and gives you a much simplified interface to implement.

I happen to work for Simba, so I'm a bit biased, but using an SDK does make it fairly easy to create an ODBC driver for whatever you're trying to do. You can get something going in 5 days if you're somewhat proficient at coding.

One of the other posts recommends unixODBC or iODBC as starting points, however this will not work. It's important to realize the distinction between a driver manager (unixODBC, iODBC, etc) and a driver. The Driver Manager acts as the middle-man between the application and the driver, removing the need to link directly to a driver.

You could start with the Postgres or MySQL drivers as a starting point and fork them to use your own database, however this is unlikely to be a trivial task. Creating a driver from scratch is even more difficult and will likely have ongoing (and higher than expected) maintenance costs. As long as you're aware of the costs of this approach, it can be viable as well.

Comment: What's the license of the Simba SDK?

Comment: Link is dead now