# creating a custom odbc driver for application

Tags: vb6, odbc, driver

Ok, i have a simple database engine (its a proprietary product written in vb6) for one of my applications...

i'd like to create an ODBC driver for it so i can use some of my other applications (which require a database) with my database engine rather than microsoft sql (which they are currently using)....

Does anyone have any heads up on how to develop an ODBC driver (preferably in vb6) ... i'v spent the last few hours googling it and havnt had much luck... about the best thing i have found so far is: http://www.datadirect.com/products/openaccess/index.ssp

but i dont exactly want to go buying an SDK to write an ODBC driver...

Cheers in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to ask, you won't be able to do it :-) Seriously, writing an ODBC driver is big undertaking - I looked at doing so for a project I was on once, and eventually advised against trying, and I have a pretty good understanding of ODBC. And it really needs to be mostly written in a lower level language such as C or C++ - VB6 is not really suitable.

Comment: if vb6 is not an option, vc++.net is fine, im looking at the datadirect api with a win32 dll now, but not having much luck...

Comment: @neddy An ODBC driver must effectively supply a C interface to its users. Maybe you could write an OLEDB provider or something similar -  I'm afraid I don't really do .NET.

Comment: Thats ok, do you have any heads up on developing a OLEDB driver? googling that isn't providing many relevant results either :(

Comment: +1 Creating ODBC drivers is also discussed in this question - everyone agrees it is extremely difficult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335008/creating-a-custom-odbc-driver

Comment: OLEDB Providers can be somewhat more complex than the simpler ODBC driver model was back in the day.  VB6 can be used to create "simple providers" very effectively, but you'll probably want a lot more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open source one you can look at or use as a base for your stuff: http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/src/