# Server side ODBC

Tags: database, odbc, server-side

I want to implement a specific database (can't say exactly what it does), but i want to know what do i need to do to make my server odbc compliant so that any odbc library can interact with it/ i've googled it but there's only client side related stuff. [there is another post here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335008/creating-a-custom-odbc-driver), but they don't answer the question.

thanks

p.s.: this is a new program, i'm not talking of an existing rdbms

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any links, but it seems to me that the simplest solution to this issue is to

1. Take the ODBC client spec
2. Take an open source ODBC driver
3. Engineer the requirements suitable for your use case needs from this.
   .
   .
   .
4. Implement.

Answer (score 0):

To reach optimum performance you could look at a proven SDK, like the SimbaEngine SDK, which will meet your stated requirements,. Here is a link to "build an ODBC in 5 Days - http://simba.com/build-odbc-sdk-driver.htm"