# Creating an ODBC data source with Apache/MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, odbc

I have a system build using mysql/php. Currently users can get stats by downloading a csv which is built using PHP and a mysql query.
One user has asked if they can get the data using ODBC instead. 
I can find a lot of info about using PHP to connect to an ODBC data source but not for creating your own one.
Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Try this link http://www.enduserguides.com/software/db/mysqlapps/eug_create-an-odbc-connection-to-a-mysql-database.html and this: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=2545

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question abit odd.

Say users want the data to excel?
You'll install odbc-drivers for mysql and use external datasource in excel.

Notice: if you run for 32-bit odbc (32bit-office), x64-systems will have the odbc-panel in

```
c:\windir\syswow64\odbcad32.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late, but since your system is on a LAMP stack of some sort, have you considered just using MySQL as a direct ODBC data source? You can do a lot with view tables, and you might be surprised at what you can pull off at the database level.

Another way you might approach this is to create some sort of import/export mechanism in PHP that leverages special MySQL tables suited to the specific ODBC integration needs. For example, you might have a third party shipping application write tracking numbers along with some identifier to one of these import tables via ODBC. Then at some point a PHP routine can fetch the unprocessed records and do whatever.

In following the guideline that simple code is better than clever code, then building a custom ODBC solution for a scenario such as this is probably only going to cause you extra grief with little to no reward. Nevertheless, [this other relevant Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335008/creating-a-custom-odbc-driver) might offer some direction. Good luck!